# Alerts Not Firing

Tags: sql-server, raiserror

##CharlieFace answer in the comments fixed my issue.

The alerts are not triggering.

Test 1:

```
RAISERROR('Test Alert Error', 16,1)
```

... I don't get any emails .

Test 2:**strong text**

If I test with this

```
RAISERROR('Test Alert Error', 16,1) WITH LOG
```

...I **do** get the emails.

Test 1 *sans* `WITH LOG` - Generates the error, but it's not automatically written to the error log unless alerts are configured to log it. Still activates alerts based on severity

Test 2 `WITH LOG` - Logs error to SQL Server error log: Captures the error message, severity level (16), and state (1) in the server's error log, even if alerts aren't configured.

Both of these statements should trigger the email, but only one `with log` does.

I have tested sending emails from dbmail and that works. When I check the alert history, the number of occurrences are not getting incremented only when I specify with log. But based on my event definition, if I run select 1/0 ; this produces a level 16 error, and I should get the email, but I don't.

Code to create alert.

USE [msdb] GO EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_alert @name=N'Test Alerts', @message_id=0, @severity=16, @enabled=1, @delay_between_responses=0, @include_event_description_in=1, @database_name=N'', @notification_message=N'', @event_description_keyword=N'', @performance_condition=N'', @wmi_namespace=N'', @wmi_query=N'', @job_id=N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' GO EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_notification @alert_name=N'Test Alerts', @operator_name=N'alertuser', @notification_method = 1 GO

Comment: Show us your code where you set-up the alert e-mails.

Comment: Are you talking about the alerting in SQL Agent? That requires the error message to be written to the log https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-an-alert-using-severity-level?view=sql-server-ver16#Restrictions

Comment: [edit] any clarifications directly into your question.

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208361/sql-server-agent-alerts-using-severity-16 you need to call `sp_altermessage` also. Side note: `RAISERROR` is basically deprecated, you should use the new `THROW`

Comment: @Charlieface since this is a comment, I can't like your answer.  This resolved my issue. I thought that the alerts were based on the severity and did not know specific messages where turned on or off.  Also thanks for telling raiserror was depracated. I was using it to create the error without any code.  TY

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the message is being logged in the first place.

```sql
EXEC sp_altermessage @message_id = 50000, @parameter = 'WITH_LOG', @parameter_value = 'true';
```

Note that you should probably use `THROW`,where you can specify an exact error number, rather than the default 50000.

See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208361/sql-server-agent-alerts-using-severity-16